# Using PHP to get value of key from array

Tags: php

**My array is**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [week_startDate] => 2019-02-01
            [week_endDate] => 2019-02-03
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [week_startDate] => 2019-02-04
            [week_endDate] => 2019-02-10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [week_startDate] => 2019-02-11
            [week_endDate] => 2019-02-17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [week_startDate] => 2019-02-18
            [week_endDate] => 2019-02-24
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [week_startDate] => 2019-02-25
            [week_endDate] => 2019-02-28
        )

)
```

I want to get the key value of week_endDate when match week_startDate. 
suppose my week_startDate is

**Case1 expected value:** week_startDate is a 2019-02-01 match in the array then I want to return 2019-02-03

**case2 expected value:** week_startDate is a 2019-02-18 match in the array then I want to return 2019-02-24

it is possible to use an array function or any other way?

Comment: Using a loop you can do what do you want, have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this by using array_search() along with array_column(), See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$expectedDate = '2019-02-11';
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
  if($expectedDate ==$val['week_startDate']){
   return $val['week_endDate'];
  }
}
```

**Another solution**

```
$startDate = '2019-02-01';
$k = array_search($startDate, array_column($array, 'week_startDate'));
if ($k !== false) {
   echo $array[$k]['week_endDate'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) on the `week_startDate` column (extracted using [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)) to find the key for that value, and then use that key to return the `week_endDate`:

```
$startDate = '2019-02-01';
$k = array_search($startDate, array_column($array, 'week_startDate'));
if ($k !== false) {
    $endDate = $array[$k]['week_endDate'];
}
else {
    echo "$startDate not found!";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kSOCJ)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$search_on_me = array(
    array(
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-01',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-03'
    ),

    array(
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-04',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-10'
    ),

    array(
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-11',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-17'
    )
);

$key = array_search('2019-02-01', array_column($search_on_me, 'week_startDate'));

echo "week_endDate of 2019-02-01: ".$search_on_me[$key]['week_endDate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like this. But not sure which one you want. So you can check this:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if(array_key_exists('week_startDate', $arr)){
        return $arr["week_endDate"];
    }
}
```

or you can check this:

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if($arr["week_startDate"] == "2019-02-01"){
        return $arr["week_endDate"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    [
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-01',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-03'
    ], [
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-04',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-10'
    ], [
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-11',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-17'
    ], [
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-18',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-24'
    ], [
        'week_startDate' => '2019-02-25',
        'week_endDate' => '2019-02-28'
    ]
];
```

To get the key:

```
$key = array_search('2019-02-01', array_column($array, 'week_startDate'));
```

To get the value:

```
$value = $array[$key]['week_endDate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of the start dates with [array_column](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php).

```
$startDates = array_column($your_array, 'week_startDate');
```

The key for the item containing your $needle date can be found with [array_search](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php).

```
$key = array_search($needle, $startDates);
```

The return value of array_search can be false, if the $needle is not found. Make sure to check if it's 0 or false!

```
if ($key !== false) {
 $endDate = $your_array[$key]['week_endDate'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using array pointer for pointing every element

```
reset($myarray);
while ($curr = current($myarray))
{

  $key = key($myarray); // Get key of pointing array
  if ( ( $curr['week_startDate'] == $curr['week_endDate'] ) && $curr['week_startDate'] !== '2019-02-01' && $curr['week_startDate'] !== '2019-02-18' )
    print_r($curr);

  next($myarray);
}
```